# PHP cURL echoing curl_multi_exec

Tags: php, curl

With normal curl when I went on page with normal curl it gave me the source code of one page. And I could just get it as string like this :

```
$ch = curl_init();
$contents = curl_exec($ch);
echo $contents;  // echos sourcecode of one page
```

But now i have curl_multi_exec, I tried echoing it, but it gave me 0000000000000.

```
$mh = curl_multi_init();

curl_multi_add_handle($mh,$curls[0]);
curl_multi_add_handle($mh,$curls[1]);
curl_multi_add_handle($mh,$curls[2]);
curl_multi_add_handle($mh,$curls[3]);
curl_multi_add_handle($mh,$curls[4]);


$running = null;
do {
    usleep(10000);
    $sisu = curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
} while($running > 0);
echo $sisu;  // just echos 000000000000000 , but it should echo source of 5 pages
```

**What I am doing wrong?**

Comment: Well, I'm not an expert, but maybe $running = null (forgot the dollar sign)?

Comment: @NordVind : Fixed it, was just a typo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the `curl_multi_getcontent()` function and the `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` option.

There's a nice example of using the curl_multi code here: http://www.jaisenmathai.com/articles/php-curl-asynchronous.html

Answer (score 4):

Try this after the while loop:

```
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++) {
    $resps[$i] = curl_multi_getcontent($curls[$i]);
    echo $resps[$i];
}
```